# Rails truncate UTF-8 strings containing &eacute; (for example)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, truncate, multibyte-characters

I am working on a *rails 3.1* app with *ruby 1.9.3* and *mongoid* as my ORM. I am facing an annoying issue. I would like to truncate the content of a post like this:

```
<%= raw truncate(strip_tags(post.content), :length => 200) %>
```

I am using `raw` and `strip_tags` because my `post.content` is actually handled with a rich text editor.

I have a serious issue with non ASCII characters. Imagine my post content is the following:

```
éééé éééé éééé éééé éééé éééé éééé éééé
```

What I am doing above in a naive way does this:

```
éééé éééé éééé éééé éééé &eac...
```

Looks like truncate is seeing every word of the string like `&eacute;&eactute;&eacute;&eacute;`.

Is there a way to either:

1. **Have truncate handle an actual UTF-8 strings**, where 'é' stands for a single character ? That would be my favorite approach.
2. Hack the above instruction such that the result is better, like force rails to truncate between 2 words,

I am asking this question because I have not found **any** solution so far. This is the only place in my app where I have problems with such character, and it is a major issues since the whole content of the website is in french, so contains a lot of `é, ç, à, ù`.

Also, I think this behavior is quite unfortunate for the `truncate` helper because in my case it does not truncate 200 characters at all, but approximately 25 characters !

Comment: Does `post.content` use UTF-8 é or the HTML `&eacute;` entity?

Comment: Good question. How can I check that ? I would bet for &eacute. I am aware that this could a symptom of a much bigger problem, I just wanted to focus my question on something specific and simple. So maybe there is a way to handle the whole thing by making sure mongo stores UTF-8 strings, but I don't know how to check that ..

Comment: @muistooshort I updated my question to better reflect the situation. I am in a context of a striped html string. Does it help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably too late to help with your issue, but...
You can use the ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars limit method, like so:

```
post.content.mb_chars.limit(200).to_s
```

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html#method-i-limit

I was having a very similar issue (truncating strings in different languages) and this worked for my case. This is after making sure the encoding is set to UTF-8 everywhere: rails config, database config and/or database table definitions, and any html templates.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is HTML then I would suggest you check out the [truncate_html](https://github.com/hgmnz/truncate_html) gem.  I've not used it with characters like this but it should be aware of where it can safely truncate the string.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way, but not a nice solution. First you have to make sure the content you save is UTF-8. This might not necessary.

```
content = "éééé"
post.content = content.force_encoding('utf-8') unless content.encoding.to_s = "UTF-8"
```

Then when you read it you can read force it back

```
<%= raw truncate(strip_tags(post.content.force_encoding('utf-8')), :length => 200) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written [strings](https://github.com/piotrmurach/strings) to help truncate, align, wrap multibyte text with support for no whitespace languages(Japanese, Chinese etc…)

```
Strings.truncate('ラドクリフ、マラソン五輪代表に1万m出場にも含み', 12)
# => "ラドクリフ…"
```